# Trying to populate the screen with objects

Tags: java, android

it seems I have a problem understanding classes. It would be great if someone could help.

I'm trying to populate my Smartphone screen (android) with 3 circles of different color.
My problem is that by using the code below I only get one (blue) circle.

I considered that the Problem is that the y-value isn't set correctly and the 3 circles are hiding each other (so that only the blue one is visible). But when I log the y-value of the 3 circle objects, the y-values seem to be correct (200,500,800)

Whats am I doing wrong?

Thanks for your help in advance.

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public Circle circleR;
    public Circle circleG;
    public Circle circleB;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        circleR = new Circle(this, 200, 255, 0, 0);
        setContentView(circleR);

        circleG = new Circle(this, 500, 0, 255, 0);
        setContentView(circleG);

        circleB = new Circle(this, 800, 0, 0, 255);
        setContentView(circleB);

    }
}
```

```java
public class Circle extends View {

    public Paint paint;
    public int y;

    public Circle(Context context,int y, int r, int g, int b){
        super(context);

        paint=new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));

        this.y=y;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        canvas.drawCircle(30, this.y,30, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in setting the content view multiple times. Only the view set as last (the one with a blue circle) will be visible. If you want multiple circles to be visible at the same time you should draw them on one canvas localized inside one view. I rearranged your code so that it does what you wanted:

```java
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        CirclesView circlesView = new CirclesView(this);
        setContentView(circlesView);
    }
}
```

```java
public class CirclesView extends View {

    public Circle circleR;
    public Circle circleG;
    public Circle circleB;

    public CirclesView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        circleR = new Circle(200, 255, 0, 0);
        circleG = new Circle(500, 0, 255, 0);
        circleB = new Circle(800, 0, 0, 255);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){
        circleR.draw(canvas);
        circleG.draw(canvas);
        circleB.draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

```java
public class Circle {

    public Paint paint;
    public int y;

    public Circle(int y, int r, int g, int b) {
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(r,g,b));

        this.y=y;
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawCircle(30, this.y,30, paint);
    }
}
```

Circle knows how to draw itself on a canvas which will be provided to it by a view.

Comment: thank you so much for your answer. So the difference is, that I had 3 canvases each with one circle.
The correct way is to only have one canvas with 3 circles, right? Isn't it possible to have multiple canvas in Java because the overlay each other?

Comment: @mmh555 The difference is that you had three views, but (in simplification) there can be only one active view. So what you did was first setting the view to the one displaying the red circle, then changing it to the one displaying the green circle and so on. Each one was overwriting the previous.